# confusion over binding class in LINQ group by

Tags: c#

I have linq query which returns me Status and number of machines which have the status like this:

```
 STATUS  NUMBERS
-------|--------
   Run |  25
-------|--------
   STOP|  55
-------|---------
   IDLE|  88
```

but the problem is when the number of STOP is zero ,i dont see it in my query result,therefore i created a class and put all the status there:

```
public class   AllStatus
{
    public int STOP { get; set; }
    public int START_UP { get; set; }
    public int SERVICE { get; set; }
    public int RUN { get; set; }
    public int LINK_DOWN { get; set; }
    public int IDLE { get; set; }
    public int ERROR { get; set; }
    public int DATA_INCOMPLETE { get; set; }

}
```

now i need to bind this class with my query result ,in this way even if any status is present because its zero,i can put zero in its status ,the following query returns me 10 diffrent datalist and not a single datalist with all status

```
        var result1 = (from s in _db.masterData
                       group s by s.current_turbine_status into g
                       select new 
                       {
                           status = g.Key,
                           numberOfMachines = g.Count(),
                           
                       }
                    ).ToList().Select(a => new AllStatus
                    {
                        STOP = a.status == "STOP" ? a.numberOfMachines : 0,
                        RUN = a.status == "RUN" ? a.numberOfMachines : 0,
                        IDLE = a.status == "IDLE" ? a.numberOfMachines : 0,
                        LINK_DOWN = a.status == "LINK_DOWN" ? a.numberOfMachines : 0,
                        SERVICE= a.status == "SERVICE" ? a.numberOfMachines : 0,
                        DATA_INCOMPLETE = a.status == "DATA_INCOMPLETE" ? a.numberOfMachines : 0

                    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a job for `ToLookup`. Try this:

```
var lookup = _db.masterData.ToLookup(x => x.current_turbine_status);

var result1 = new
{
    STOP = lookup["STOP"].Count(),
    RUN = lookup["RUN"].Count(),
    IDLE = lookup["IDLE"].Count(),
    LINK_DOWN = lookup["LINK_DOWN"].Count(),
    SERVICE = lookup["SERVICE"].Count(),
    DATA_INCOMPLETE = lookup["DATA_INCOMPLETE"].Count(),
};
```

Comment: what does LookUp do that JOIN does not?

Comment: @ilmagnifico - `ToLookup` and `Join` are two different things. There's no `Join` in your query, btw. Did you mean `GroupBy`? `GroupBy` created a list of your statuses. You just wanted a single object and `ToLookup` gives you that.

Comment: yes i meant group by ,and another YES for your nice solution,works :) thanks